# Best way to use and install Linux (Ubuntu) using two hard drives

Tags: ubuntu, windows, swap

I'm currently looking to switch from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (not dual-booting, Ubuntu only).

On Windows I've used my 128GB SSD for OS-files almost exclusively, while all other stuff goes to my 2TB SSHD.

How do I effectively use both my hard-drives on Linux? Can I, like on Windows, have the Linux OS-files set-up on my SSD for a fast boot and all other files on my SSHD?

I've read that my "swap partition" should be on my SSHD since it's so large in size. How much size should I give it when I have 16GB DDR3 ram?

I'm open to suggestions, I just want my new install to go smoothly and not waste an entire hard drive.

Thanks.

Comment: You will struggle to use more that 20GB for system partition. Latter you can symlink to make part of the ssd part of your home.

Answer (score 0):

- Keep system (`/usr`, `/lib` etc) on SSD - this will result in faster system start and app launches.
- Keep volatile data (`/var` and `/tmp`) on SSHD - this should help with SSD life
- `/home` obviously on SSHD as it will contain a lot of data
- swap on SSHD is a good idea. You can keep your options open with swap file instead of partition, which if set up properly shouldn't be any worse. I'd start with 4 GB (unless you want to suspend2disk or do a lot of very memory-intensive operations) See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04 for instructions on how to setup the swap file (after installation)

This way will probably result in smaller usage of SSD. I can with tiny compromises fit myself on a 16GB SSD with my system. But you can always symlink some files from SSD to your home, if you have some nonvolatile files that will benefit from very fast loading...

Comment: Sorry I disagree: "/home obviously on SSHD as it will contain a lot of data" `/home/$USER/` on the SSD, the configs benefit from quick loading. All directories on the SSHD (set that with `~./config/users-dirs.dirs`). Speed does not matter for personal data. Extra benefit: a backup for personal data is a lot easier this way.

Comment: @Rinzwind: Yes, that is a possible alternative. I don't see the configs needing that much boost, but yes, this might help a little...

Comment: My systems boot is 0.7s quicker when I do it like that (it was a small sample: 5 boots each with and without on a vanilla Ubuntu 17.04).